# PHP Image upload not working, no data inserted into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just creating a simple image upload to MySQL

```html
<form method="post" action="quanly.php" class="form-group justify-content-center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image">
                 <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col text-center">
                  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="add_btn" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Submit</button>
               </div>
            </form>
```

And my php code:

```php
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['name']));
   $query = "INSERT INTO tasks (image) VALUES ('$image')";
   mysqli_query($db, $query); //db is the mysql connection
```

The `image` in MySQl is LONGBLOB.
THE PROBLEM: when I try to submit an image, no data was in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **file_get_contents** from image tags.

```
$image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $query = "INSERT INTO tasks (image) VALUES ('$image')";
   mysqli_query($db, $query); //db is the mysql connection
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$target_dir = "quanly/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>

 $target_dir = "quanly/" - specifies the directory where the file is going to be placed.
 $target_file specifies the path of the file to be uploaded
 $uploadOk=1 is not used yet (will be used later)
 $imageFileType holds the file extension of the file (in lower case)
```

Next, check if the image file is an actual image or a fake image

Try this..